# how to measure current of a galvanic cell with a voltmeter

Tags: current, current-measurement

I was wondering how I could measure the current generated by my galvanic cell: can I just directly connect my voltmeter to the two electrodes of my cell, or do I have to put it in series?

Comment: an schematic would be helpful

Comment: Do you have an estimate or rough idea or expectation of how much current will flow? Will this be with a load attached, or are you wanting to measure the short-circuit current? And what is the voltage of the cell?

Comment: the voltage is 0.852 V

Comment: Do you want to measure the maximum current it can deliver? In other words the short-circuit current?

Comment: yes that is what I want to do

Comment: Can you tell more about the cell? Do you know how much current it might be able to supply, even a rough estimate? You have told us nothing about the cell. Is it going to put out 0.1A, 1A, 10A, 100A, 1000A?

Comment: @mkeith I figured out that I need to make a discharge curve and the ways to do it. But I really want to thank you for all the help.

Comment: Great! Maybe you can write up an answer to your own question to help out people who find this question by search in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful! Consider that a current meter is almost a **short circuit** and a voltage meter is an open circuit.

Be clear if your meter measures voltage or current or both, usually you have to change some probe connections in order to select what to measure.

Current measurement is done in series connection, voltage in parallel.